# Add Gridview to a static template causing UI design changes

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, windows

I am new to xaml.. just started learning.

I have designed a static template using Grid. I need this grid to repeat based on the object based from C#

Hence i have included GridView and binding to do it.

Before adding Gridview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ZpW.png)

After adding Grid view to the Grid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9LHi.png)

My code in XAML

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UpcomingEvent}}"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Padding="0"
              Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Height="auto">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid Name="DataLabels">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="7">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD3D3D3" Offset="0" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Grid Margin="7">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="30"  Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding Month}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  Text="{Binding Year}"></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Heading}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Time}"></TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FFD3D3D3" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
```

C# code:

```
    public List<UpcommingEvent> GetUpcomingEvent()
    {
        List<UpcommingEvent> data = new List<UpcommingEvent>();
        data.Add(new UpcommingEvent() { Date = "2", Time = "00:45AM", Description = "fds My first dynamic message 1", Heading = "Fist Message", Month = "Dec", Year = "2015" });
        data.Add(new UpcommingEvent() { Date = "3", Time = "01:45AM", Description = "rewd My first dynamic message 2", Heading = "Second Message", Month = "Dec", Year = "2015" });
        data.Add(new UpcommingEvent() { Date = "4", Time = "01:45AM", Description = "fdf My first dynamic message 3", Heading = "Second Message", Month = "Dec", Year = "2015" });
        data.Add(new UpcommingEvent() { Date = "5", Time = "01:00PM", Description = "vfc My first dynamic message 4", Heading = "Second Message", Month = "Dec", Year = "2015" });
        data.Add(new UpcommingEvent() { Date = "6", Time = "12:45PM", Description = "kjh My first dynamic message 5", Heading = "Second Message", Month = "Dec", Year = "2015" });
        return data;
    }

    public DashboardPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        UpcomingEvent.Source = GetUpcomingEvent();
    }
```

What is causing the dunamic UI to differ from Static and how should i fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing something here. Your static UI is showing Date part in the center. But in your XAML code, there is no such property set.

Comment: Do you mean the 9 Dec 2015 ? .I have added the date from (Date, Month and year) of the object. In the Image with dynamic data the date 2 Dec 2015, 3 Dec 2015 are there.

<TextBlock FontSize="30"  Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding Month}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  Text="{Binding Year}"></TextBlock>

Comment: How 9 Dec 2015 are appearing in  the center ?

Comment: Thats is the static UI i did.. I had that copied into the list view and the Ui started to appear this way. Message displayed is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have typed GridView instead of ListView. There is no ItemTemplate present in GridView.

I have done some changes to your template :

```
<ListView x:Name="LstView1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid Name="DataLabels" Width="400">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="7">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid Margin="7" Background="Purple">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Month}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Year}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Heading}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Time}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Check the template and tell if it fit your needs.